# How to make list of integers with a start, length and increment in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I would like to generate a list of integers.  I have the starting value, the increment value and the length of the list.

I know this should be simple, but I can't crack it.  I have tried list comprehensions, Stream functions, etc.

Here is what I've tried and what didn't work:

A range allows me to choose the start and end, but not the increment

```
1..3 |> Enum.to_list()
```

This list comprehension works, but is it the "best" way?

```
start = 1
length = 3
increment = 2
for i <- 0..length-1, do: start + i*increment
```

Comment: to the downvoter, please tell me how to improve the question.  I've searched for this, but couldn't find it.  If it is easy, please share!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a comprehension:

```
for x <- 1..10, do: x * 3
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30]
```

In the above example, the following are the values you specified:

```
start = 1
length = 10
increment = 3
```

You will need additional parentheses for a negative range:

```
for x <- -1..(-10), do: x * 3 
[-3, -6, -9, -12, -15, -18, -21, -24, -27, -30]
```

Comment: thanks Gazler, I was stuck on trying to only use + with an accumulator value

Answer (score 5):

The answer by Gazler is a great one.

If you'd like to get a little bit more fancy you can use `Stream.iterate/2` and `Enum.take/2` for a similar result:

```
start = 1
length = 10
increment = 3
Stream.iterate(start, &(&1 + increment)) |> Enum.take(length)
#=> [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28]
```

Comment: ah ha!  this is what I was originally trying to do.  I couldn't figure out the lambda.  Thank you!

Comment: This approach has the advantage that `Stream` is `lazy`: useful when you don't know the `length` value at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `:lists.seq(From, To, Increment)`.

```
:lists.seq(start, length*increment, increment)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very concise alternative in pure Elixir.

```
> Enum.to_list(50..150//5)
[50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135,140, 145, 150]

> Enum.to_list(3..30//5)
[3, 8, 13, 18, 23, 28]
```

The `//` part is called `range step operator`: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.14/Kernel.html#..///3